# setStringValue with AppleScript List

Tags: xcode, applescript, applescript-objc

I’m using this code to add each selected track in iTunes to a list in AppleScript Obj-C:

```
    tell application "iTunes"
        set these_titles to {}
        if selection is not {} then
            set mySelection to selection
            repeat with aTrack in mySelection
                if class of aTrack is file track then
                    set end of these_titles to ((name of aTrack) as string)
                end if
            end repeat
        end if
    end tell
```

I have this line to show the output in a text box in the GUI:

```
    trackTable's setStringValue_(these_titles)
```

But it comes out like this:

[image: Output of setStringValue]

Is there any way I can get each list item on one line, sans the quotation marks and brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the proper output for a list. If you want it coerced to a string in a particular format, you need to do that explicitly. Simply change the delimiter used for lists and then coerce the variable into a string, which will place that delimiter as text between each list item.
So, add this code to the end of your code:

```
set oldTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
set these_titles to these_titles as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldTID
```

Change the delimiter to whatever you want, in place of the comma and space.

Comment: Super! I used this with the first line changed to `set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\n"` and got exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Because this topic is related to AppleScriptObjC I want to show this as well.

```
set these_titles to these_titles's componentsJoinedByString:", "
```